# Location animation used in Google Map

Tags: google-maps-mobile, google-maps-sdk-ios

I use Google Map in my ios app and I like to show the location animation used in the Google Map.That animation is normally used for displaying the current location and is auto-resizing, i.e. the marker size is animated like self growing in light blue colour.
I like to display that animation for my latitude and longitude positon.
How can I program it?
I don't have enough reputation to upload image.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just set `myLocationEnabled`, eg:

```
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: No just like that is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the animation to your location use `animateToLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location`:

```
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[mapView animateToLocation:mapView.myLocation];
```

or you can use `animateToCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)cameraPosition` to even adjust the zoom

```
GMSCameraPosition *cameraPosition = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:mapView.myLocation zoom:14.0f;
[mapView animateToCameraPosition:cameraPosition];
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the delay, he wants to see the map animated and scrolling/zooming to the current location, the iOS animation with animateToxxx is too fast and just looks ugly compared with android sdk.

Comment: Is there a way to slow down the animation?